# Rails forms - Submitting to subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to rails, apologize if the answer is obvious. 
If I have 2 models, a user and comments, a (1 : N) relationship.
When a I create a user I am also creating a comment.

The trouble I am having is how do I write the form, or is it inherent in the user class that the comment will be associated with the user?

```
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_area :comment ???? %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a model for comments so....

Add this in user.rb

```
has_many :comments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

And in your controller?

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.comments.build
end
```

And in your form view:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :comments do |comment_form| %>
    <%= comment_form.text_field :description %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your User form is correct, you just need to add comment as an attribute in your User model. You dont need a separate comment model for this.

```
# schema

create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.text     "comment"
t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
```

You can create a migration to add the comment attribute to your User model

```
rails g migration add_comment_to_user comment:text
```

and you can drop the Comment model if this is all you need

Then you can use the form as you have it

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You may want to add some labels to your form also

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :comment %>
  <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this gets you on the right track

Comment: But if I attempt to add additional comments to the user class will this not work? Just overwrite ?

Comment: I was just assuming you wanted a single comment on the user form. Yea if you want to do more than add a simple comment in the user form you will have to add a comment model and do accepts_nested_attributes_for. If you want to add comments on the user model and on something like a posts model, look into polymorphic associations. Its a little more advanced but worth the effort. You could make users and posts, etc. commentable to use comments on multiple models.